# Close EventHubConsumerClient with a request

Tags: python, azure, python-asyncio, azure-eventhub

I have this code:

```
async def run_events_listener():
    # Create an Azure blob checkpoint store to store the checkpoints.
    checkpoint_store = BlobCheckpointStore.from_connection_string(os.getenv('CHECKPOINT_STORE_URI'), os.getenv('CHECKPOINT_CONTAINER'))

    # Create a consumer client for the event hub.
    client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(
        os.getenv('EVENTS_HUB_URI'), consumer_group="$Default",
        eventhub_name=os.getenv('EVENTHUB_NAME'), checkpoint_store=checkpoint_store)
    async with client:
        # Call the receive method. Read from the beginning of the partition (starting_position: "-1")
        await client.receive(on_event=on_event,  starting_position="-1")
```

In order to implement graceful stop, I have to close EventHubConsumerClient correctly. `run_events_listener` is an `asyncio.Task`. How should I close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no action that callers need to explicitly take to shut down cleanly.  The consumer internally manages the startup/shutdown steps via a [try/finally](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/azure/eventhub/_consumer_client.py#L356) block.

Terminating your process should or cancelling the `asyncio` task is sufficient to clean things up.

Answer (score -1):

- The consumer is in charge of efficient resource management, aiming to keep resource usage low during periods of idleness and managing health during periods of increased use.
- When the application is closing down, calling either the `CloseAsync(CancellationToken)` or `DisposeAsync()` method will ensure that network resources and other unmanaged objects are appropriately cleaned away.
- [CloseAsync(CancellationToken)](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/5.4.1/api/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Consumer/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Consumer.EventHubConsumerClient.html#Azure_Messaging_EventHubs_Consumer_EventHubConsumerClient_CloseAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) closes the consumer.
- [DisposeAsync()](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/5.4.1/api/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Consumer/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Consumer.EventHubConsumerClient.html#Azure_Messaging_EventHubs_Consumer_EventHubConsumerClient_DisposeAsync) completes the work of cleaning up the `EventHubConsumerClient`'s resources, including ensuring that the client has been closed.
- `IsClosed` [specifies](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/5.4.1/api/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Consumer/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Consumer.EventHubConsumerClient.html#Azure_Messaging_EventHubs_Consumer_EventHubConsumerClient_IsClosed) whether or not this EventHubConsumerClient has been closed.

Comment: This references the C# API and isn't helpful to address the question being asked.  The Python clients deviate from other languages in their API shape.